# Autodesk Construction Cloud API - Create new Project

Tags: rest, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-construction-cloud

I'am trying to implement an integration with Autodesk Construction Cloud, and I want to sync my projects from my app to Autodesk.

It's not an issue to create projects with BIM 360 API, it works just as expected. [Link](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-POST/)

Bad thing here is that BIM 360 projects POST endpoint is not forward-compatible with ACC.
[Proof](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/overview/bim-360-compatibility/compatibility-table/)

I cannot find a way to create projects via REST with Autodesk Construction Cloud type. It seems only possible to update project's image([Link](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/projects-:project_id-image-PATCH/)), and it not helps me.

Do anybody know if it possible at all to create ACC projects with REST?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no API for creating ACC projects currently. It's a high-demand request logged as ACSADMIN-2707. Please stay tuned with us.

Comment: Any ETA? Trying to do this now :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that info on my hand, but please check out the `What's in pipeline` section of the video of `Autodesk Construction Cloud API Updates` on https://forge.autodesk.com/dev-days to know the last updates.

Comment: Unfortunately, The page you’re looking for doesn’t exist. @EasonKang any updates on this? Trying to do this now also. :-)

Comment: Sorry for missing that. Please refer to this video instead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6IwvSek4rA and this newsletter: https://constructionblog.autodesk.com/20-releases-for-autodesk-construction-cloud/?fbclid=IwAR3ncpuzvhGz-3rc2141zi7e0tLD41Zf_F_PfEq3AEZNFjpLUYzUQ54nOGw#acc

Comment: Any updates on an ETA for project creation in ACC?

Comment: @BretThompson ACC Admin API is under private beta now. Could you send me your APS Client ID and [ACC Account ID](https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Where-to-find-the-Autodesk-Construction-Cloud-Account-ID.html) to `aps (DOT) help (AT) autodesk (DOT) com`? I can help ask our engineering team if the private beta is still applicable.

Answer (score 0):

The api endpoint to create projects is there now, and works great.
Jou can choose a template to use which then generates the folder structure, workflows, custom attributes etc etc

Comment: Can you provide a source/link?

Answer (score 0):

```
url_create_project = f'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/admin/v1/accounts/{accountid}/projects'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {auth_code}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
data = {
    "name": "testproject ACC",
    "classification": "production",
    "startDate": "2024-01-01",
    "endDate": "2030-12-31",
    "type": "Single-Family Housing",
    "projectValue": {
        "value": 0,
        "currency": "EUR"
    },
    "jobNumber": "00000000",
    "addressLine1": "strees 21",
    "city": "ciry",
    "postalCode": "5702LD",
    "country": "NL",
    "timezone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
    "constructionType": "New Construction",
    "platform": "acc",
    "template": {
        "projectId": "abcdef56-32dr-3ed5-4657-23445edr45ff"
                      
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is a reply to my comment, then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78217993/edit) your current answer to add this information (and delete this answer please)